# Problem in Telegram bot logic on node-telegram-bot-api

Tags: javascript, api

Just starting to learn JS and NodeJs in general. I’m writing a TG bot just as a project to gain knowledge and experience in JS, in general, that’s not the point! Faced such a problem in the event handler: I have something like a registration window with keyboard_inline, where when the /start command comes out several buttons with a gender selection

> ```
> bot.onText(/\/start/, async msg => {
> db.get("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = ?", [msg.chat.id], async (no, yes) => {
>     yes ? 
>     console.log('ss')
>     : await bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, msg.chat.first_name + ',' + ' ' + 'добро пожаловать! \n\n' + 
>     'Вы ещё у нас не зарегистрированы! Пожалуйста, выберите свой пол для продолжения регистрации:', keyboardName(signup));
> }); });
> ```

There is a database, but this is not the point, the check is disabled there, it does not affect it in any way. But the actual call to the keyboardName function, made it to simplify the readability of the code

```
    const keyboardName = (name) => {
    return {
        reply_markup: JSON.stringify ({
            inline_keyboard: name
        })
    }
};
```

Here are the buttons:

```
const signup = [
    [  
      {
        text: ' Я парень',
        callback_data: 'signup_man'
      },
      {
        text: ' Я девушка',
        callback_data: 'signup_woman'
      }
    ]
];
```

And here is the button click event handler itself:

```
bot.on('callback_query', async query => {
    switch (query.data) {
        case 'signup_man':
            await bot.sendMessage(query.message.chat.id, 'Введи возраст от 16 до 90');
            bot.on('message', async msg => {
                if (msg.text >= 1 && msg.text <= 90) {
                    return await bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'это тестовое сообщение');
                } else
                bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'Возраст от 16 до 90');
            })

            break;
        case 'signup_woman':
            bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'С тобой приятно иметь дело! А теперь введи свой возраст, просто в чат, цифрами :)');
            break;
    }
});
```

The problem is this: when you use the bot from one account, then all the logic and checks work properly, but if I launch several more accounts at the same time, then in the last paragraph, when entering the age of the user (chat.id), several messages will be sent to the chat ( commensurate with the number of accounts with a running bot and clicking on the button). I would like to understand what is wrong and why it happens)

Tried a lot of things, but I don't seem to understand the logic

Answer (score -1):

This happens because each button click adds another handler.
Big problem of node-telegram-bot-api that you cannot use some handler in other case and not use in another.

To handle this, you can create and "array" that will contain user ids and their stages. You can check my implementation of this logic

https://github.com/Blabolka/five-minutes-to-three-tg-bot/blob/master/src/common/services/StageManager.ts

And here the example of using:

[USING EXAMPLE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ0R7.png)

In your case, you need to declare your `bot.on('message')` handler initialization on the same level with `bot.on('callback_query')` and write some if condition in `bot.on('message')` handler that will check if user clicked on any of the buttons

Comment: Please use proper formatting and code blocks instead of images.